# Strategy to refresh/update SessionFactory in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

HI I am using spring integration extensively in my project and in the current case dynamically creating my ftp, sftp adapters using spring dynamic flow registration. Also to provide session-factories I create them dynamically based on persisted configuration for each unique connection .

This works great but sometimes there are situations when I need to modify an existing session config dynamically and in this case I do require the session factory to refresh with a new session config . This can happen due to changing creds dynamically.

To do the same I am looking for two approches

1. remove the dynamic flows via flowcontext.remove(flowid). But this does not somehow kill the flow, I still see the old session factory and flow running.
2. If there is a way to associate a running adapter with a new Sessionfactory dynamically this would also work . But still have not find a way to accomplish this .

Please help

**UPDATE**

my dynamic registration code below

```
 CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile> csf = cache.get(feed.getConnectionId());
    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
                .from(inboundAdapter(csf).preserveTimestamp(true)//
                      .remoteDirectory(feed.getRemoteDirectory())//
                      .regexFilter(feed.getRegexFilter())//
                      .deleteRemoteFiles(feed.getDeleteRemoteFiles())
                      .autoCreateLocalDirectory(feed.getAutoCreateLocalDirectory())
                      .localFilenameExpression(feed.getLocalFilenameExpression())//
                      .localFilter(localFileFilter)//
                      .localDirectory(new File(feed.getLocalDirectory())),
                      e -> e.id(inboundAdapter.get(feed.getId())).autoStartup(false)
                            .poller(Pollers//
                                  .cron(feed.getPollingFreq())//
                                  .maxMessagesPerPoll(1)//
                                  .advice(retryAdvice)))
                .enrichHeaders(s -> s.header(HEADER.feed.name(), feed))//
                .filter(selector)//
                .handle(fcHandler)//
                .handle(fileValidationHandler)//
                .channel(ftbSubscriber)//
                .get();

          this.flowContext.registration(flow).addBean(csf).//
                id(inboundFlow.get(feed.getId())).//
                autoStartup(false).register();
```

I am trying removing the same via

```
flowContext.remove(flowId);
```

on removing also the poller and adapter still look like they are active

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create FTPClient
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:275)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:200)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:62)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:134)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:224)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:65)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy188.call(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

***POST Gary comments *** changed the order of the chain and removing autostartup as defined in his example and now the polling adapter looks like getting removed .

changed order to match the one from Gary and remove autostartup from the flowcontext chain. Though looks like bug is still there if autstrtup is true .

```
   this.flowContext.registration(flow).//
        id(inboundFlow.get(feed.getId()))//
        .addBean(sessionFactory.get(feed.getId()), csf)//
        .register();
```

*** researching more ***
The `standardIntegrationFlow.start` does start all the components inside the flow irrespective of the autostartup status . I guess we do need to check the isAutostartup for these as well and only start them if autostartup is True when starting the IntegrationFlow. existing code below of standardIF . I there a way to override this or does this need a PR or fix .

```
if (!this.running) {
            ListIterator<Object> iterator = this.integrationComponents.listIterator(this.integrationComponents.size());
            this.lifecycles.clear();
            while (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
                Object component = iterator.previous();
                if (component instanceof SmartLifecycle) {
                    this.lifecycles.add((SmartLifecycle) component);
                    ((SmartLifecycle) component).start();
                }
            }
            this.running = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove()` should shut everything down. If you are using `CachingSessionFactory` we need to `destroy()` it, so it closes the cached sessions.

The flow will automatically `destroy()` the bean if you add it to the registration (using `addBean()`).

If you can edit your question to show your dynamic registration code, I can take a look.

**EDIT**

Everything works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So43916317Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So43916317Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext context;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        CSF csf = new CSF(sf());
        IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(csf)
                    .localDirectory(new File("/tmp/foo"))
                    .remoteDirectory("bar"), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1_000)))
                .handle(System.out::println)
                .get();
        this.context.registration(flow)
            .id("foo")
            .addBean(csf)
            .register();
        Thread.sleep(10_000);
        System.out.println("removing flow");
        this.context.remove("foo");
        System.out.println("destroying csf");
        csf.destroy();
        Thread.sleep(10_000);
        System.out.println("exiting");
        Assert.state(csf.destroyCalled, "destroy not called");
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost("10.0.0.3");
        sf.setUsername("ftptest");
        sf.setPassword("ftptest");
        return sf;
    }

    public static class CSF extends CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile> {

        private boolean destroyCalled;

        public CSF(SessionFactory<FTPFile> sessionFactory) {
            super(sessionFactory);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
            this.destroyCalled = true;
            super.destroy();
        }

    }

}
```

log...

```
16:15:38.898 [task-scheduler-5] DEBUG o.s.i.f.i.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer - 0 files transferred
16:15:38.898 [task-scheduler-5] DEBUG o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
16:15:39.900 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.integration.util.SimplePool - Obtained org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession@149a806 from pool.
16:15:39.903 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.f.r.s.CachingSessionFactory - Releasing Session org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession@149a806 back to the pool.
16:15:39.903 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.integration.util.SimplePool - Releasing org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession@149a806 back to the pool
16:15:39.903 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.f.i.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer - 0 files transferred
16:15:39.903 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
removing flow
16:15:40.756 [main] INFO  o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter - stopped org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0
16:15:40.757 [main] INFO  o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application.foo.channel#0' has 0 subscriber(s).
16:15:40.757 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - stopped org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
16:15:40.757 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'foo': [org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer#0, org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0, org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0.source, foo.channel#0, com.example.So43916317Application$$Lambda$12/962287291#0, org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0, foocom.example.So43916317Application$CSF#0]
destroying csf
16:15:40.757 [main] DEBUG o.s.integration.util.SimplePool - Removing org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession@149a806 from the pool
exiting
16:15:50.761 [main] TRACE o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Publishing event in org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@27c86f2d: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent[source=org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication@5c18016b]
```

As you can see, the polling stops after the `remove()` and the session is closed by the `destroy()`.

**EDIT2**

If you have auto start turned off you have to start via the registration...

```
IntegrationFlowRegistration registration = this.context.registration(flow)
    .id("foo")
    .addBean(csf)
    .autoStartup(false)
    .register();
...
registration.start();
```

Comment: added the code there . Also after closing the sessions can we instruct caching session factory to try and add new session-factories based on a diff config . Guess I will need to customize the sessionfactory in that case .

Comment: I'll take a look to see what's happening; since you are adding the csf as a bean, it should be destroyed ok. You could also look at using a `DelegatingSessionFactory` with a custom `SessionFactoryLocator` - and change the delegate factory at runtime.

Comment: ahh ok let me first remove the bean addition , will take a look at DelegatingSessionFactory for the runtime swapping .Thanks

Comment: I've confirmed it's a bug - you could call `destroy()` manually on the csf. It's actually fixed already; we just need to release 1.2.2.

Comment: ahh ok then in this case currently let me try if I can kill the same and then refresh the same somehow from the SessionFactoryLocator .So for deleting the entire flow I guess I will also need to add deleting its associated sessionfactory

Comment: Hi Garry can I get the changes you guys made to delete the associated beans as well as I am somehow not figuring a way to delete the associated session factory as I get that from a cache I maintain even though I do destroy but stlll I get exceptions from the already associated factory . Seems the poller is still running adde exception in question

Comment: Hmmm - the `remove()` should stop the poller; let me see if I can reproduce. The fix to destroy the factory is in 1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (but don't use that in production).

Comment: Works for me - see my edit - I am using DSL 1.2.1.RELEASE.

Comment: hmm looks good at your end are you using spring integration core 4.3.8 on the dsl I still use 4.3.8

Comment: 4.3.9 but I doubt that's causing a difference.

Comment: yup true that also doesn't help , the remove method does remove the adapter (apparent when I search for the same in applicationcontext) but the I do not get to the remove/destroy methods of the poller ,consumer .via debug also no logs appear as they do in your trace .  The thread for the poller keeps on trying via the session factory .Anyways need to dig to find some workaround.

Comment: finally got it working but weird change the order did the trick not sure why though change in edit .

Comment: also updated comments seems there is a bug when you have flow autostartup =false added , the cleanup is not graceful .maybe adding the same to your test case above shall replicate it .

Comment: If you have `autoStartup=false`, how are you starting the flow? You don't seem to be saving a reference to the registration. See my second edit - it still works as expected.

Comment: Yes I guess the you are right and in my initial code I was setting the inbound adapter and flow autostartup as false, I also have a separate schedule which starts these, but the code there was only starting the inbound ftp adapter not the IntegrationFlow . I think because of this when I tried to destroy/remove the integration flow it somehow was not cleaning up the ftp adapter . I will run some tests to confirm this theory .

Comment: If the flow is not `running` when it's stopped, it doesn't "know" that it has to stop its components. See `StandardIntegrationFlow.stop()`.

Comment: Ahh thanks Gary that explains it , thanks for all your help solved a blocking issue for me. Now we have a great dynamic app  on SI , with full control over the life cycle ☺️

Comment: Also one last question @gary-russel when you have a autostarted Integration flow does it also start up the inbound adapter . I mean though the adapter autostartup is set as false the adapter seems to run when the flow is generated .I have not explicitly invoked the adapter yet at this instance. I there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: When the flow is started (directly, or via its `IntegrationFlowRegistration`, it starts all of its components. Similarly if it is stopped (and is `running`) it stops all of its components.

Comment: Yup it does checked the code but shouldn't it not start child components which have autostartup=false

Comment: No; it's designed that way. `autoStartup` is explicitly for preventing components being started by the application context (or in this case the dynamic flow) during initialization. If you `start()` an application context, all `Lifecycle` beans are started, even `SmartLifecycle` with `autoStartup=false`. It only controls the initial state; an explicit `start()` of the container (context or registration) will start all components. The dynamic flow is therefore consistent with the way the application context works with respect to bean life cycles.

Comment: Oh ok got it so I'll need to control the initial flow startup with inbound adapter  startup of the flow to prevent it from starting automatically, post that I can handle components life cycle seperatly.

Comment: No; you should consider the flow as a single object that has a lifecycle and it controls the lifecycle of its components. You shouldn't reference those components directly.

Comment: Ya I can handle it with IntegrationFlowRegistration but only issue I have is to know when the flow is running programatically like I was doing using the child AbstractEndpoint previously , it does not expose any isRunning method currently. If I can figure that out I will be good with treating the whole flow as a single custom component .

Comment: You can cast the `IntegrationFlow` to `SmartLifeCycle`.

Comment: That would be great , also if there was a way to get all registrations currently registered in the registry which I guess does not expose it currently